# How to use request.getParameterValues?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I'm trying to pass an array from one jsp page to another using a hidden form.

Here is the relevant code of my jsp files.

```
<td style="vertical-align: top;"><button onclick="getPlayerNames()"id="generate">Generate</button><br></td>


<form id="playerNames" method="post" action="lineups.jsp">
<input type="hidden" id="players" />
</form>

<script>
    function getPlayerNames(){
          var selected = document.querySelectorAll("#selected-players > tr > td");
          var playernames = [];
          for(var i=0; i<selected.length; ++i){
             //alert(selected[i].textContent);
             var num = (i-1)%6;
         if(num==0){
             playernames.push(selected[i].textContent);
         }


      }
      document.getElementById("players").values=playernames;
      alert(document.getElementById("players").values);
      document.getElementById("playerNames").submit();
}</script>
```

The alert message does show that the correct values are being placed in "players"

Then on my lineup.jsp I have:

```
<%String[] s = request.getParameterValues("players");
System.out.println(s[0]);%>
```

and I get a null pointer exception on the line with 'System.out.println(s[0]);'

Comment: Can you just try with `request.getParameter("players")`?

Comment: When I do that it says "can not convert from string to String[]" so I switch s to a string and 'System.out.println(s)' prints "null"

Comment: You need to assing it  to `String s = request.getParameter("players")`

Comment: Yes I did that and the outcome was null.

Comment: You will need to add name attribute to hidden field and use that in request.getParameter();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. name attribute is not specified to input tag, if name attribute not specified then no value will be sent.
2. In your case `request.getParameter` and `request.getParameterValues` return same value because `players` element is specified only one. When you use `request.getParameter` it'll return direct `string`, `request.getParameterValues` will return `string[]` with length `1`.

If you want to send multiple players and you don't want to repeat element in your jsp, then concat the `players` with some special character like the following:

```
document.getElementById("players").value=playernames.join("::");
```

You can get is as string in `lineup.jsp` and you can split it with the same special characters like the following:

```
<%
   String players = request.getParameter("players");
   String[] s = players.split("::");
%>
```

Comment: Thank you I this helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

String[] players = request.getParametervalues("nameOfTheHiddenField");

Please try specifying a name for the hidden field and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

OK, s is null here hence `s[0]` throws `NullPointerException`

The method `getParameterValues()` will generally come into picture if there is a chance of getting multiple values for any input parameter, 
this method will retrieve all of it values and return it as string array.

but in your case I think you have only one value to fetch, use `request.getAttribute` and try to print the result i.e. s and not s[0]

once s is not null , you can go for s[0]