# request.getParameter() returns null with regular JS, but works for jQuery

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

Here is the working jQuery version:

```
var button = $('#a');
var output = $('#output');

var data = {
  colors: ['red', 'blue', 'green']
};

button.click(function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "handler.jsp",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
      output.html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

And here is the vanilla JS version that doesn't work:

```
var button = document.querySelector('#a');
var output = document.querySelector('#output');

var data = {
  colors: ['red', 'blue', 'green']
};

button.onclick = function() {
  var request = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  };

  fetch('handler.jsp', request)
    .then(function(response) { 
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(text) {
      output.innerHTML = text;
    });
};
```

The Java code:

```
<%
String[] colors = request.getParameterValues("colors[]");
%>

<p><%= colors[0] %></p>
```

In both cases, the request/response works, however the response with the vanilla JS returns

```
<p>null</p>
```

While the jQuery version returns

```
<p>red</p>
```

What is wrong with the vanilla JS version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use request.getParameterValues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307855/how-to-use-request-getparametervalues)

Comment: I suspect the server interprets the requests differently because of different headers sent. Can you see the request that is send with jQuery and set same headers on fetch request? Specifically look for content-type header